# Keep array items between boundary limits

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linear-programming

I need to generate an algorithm for a production queue, and I am sure that this has been solved before. It looks like a standard problem, but I can not find any reference, so I am a bit puzzled...

Let's say that I have an array of items with two values:

- `start_date`
- `delivery_date`

Items can not enter the queue before start_date, and should exit the queue before delivery_date. That is, every item should be "processed" in the interval (start_date, delivery_date].

min_date and max_date are also arbitraries. For some items is a 3 day interval, while for other items it maybe a 3 year interval.

Then, for every day in the calendar, I've the capacity to process an arbitrary number of items.

- 2016-02-01: 60 items
- 2016-02-02: 30 items
- 2016-02-03: 45 items
- 2016-02-04:   0 items
- 2016-02-05: 48 items

What I need is to confirm that given the calendar capacity, our system will be able to fit all the items into the production queue.

On a first look, I thought on some really simple ordering (`delivery_date desc`, `start_date asc`), but it is obvious that this does not do the trick.

Do you guys know of any standard algorithm or any development library to do this?

PS: It will also be great if I could know how much spare capacity I have for a given interval `[start_date, delivery_date]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can formulate this as a [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem), and solve it with the [network simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simplex_algorithm).

Create a graph G with:

- A source vertex s
- A sink vertex t
- A vertex u_i for each job i
- An edge (s, u_i) of capacity 1 for each job i
- A vertex v_j for each day j in the timetable
- An edge (v_j, t) of capacity equal to the number of jobs that can be processed on day j
- An edge (u_i, v_j) of capacity 1 whenever job i can be processed on day j -- that is, whenever start_date[i] <= j <= delivery_date[i].

Now compute a maximum flow from s to t.  If the value of this flow is equal to the number n of jobs, then all jobs can be processed; if it's lower, then at most that many jobs can be processed.  (The flow can't be higher than n, since there are only n edges out of s, each of which has capacity 1.)  Either way, the network simplex algorithm will furnish you with flows of either 1 or 0 in each of the edges between a job and a day, telling you which jobs to process on which days.

The above formulation will also happily solve a more general (though perhaps not usefully so) problem in which each job i can have an arbitrary *set* of days on which it can be run, rather than being restricted to an interval of days from start_date[i] to delivery_date[i].  Because of that, I'm not certain the above is the best possible solution approach for your more restricted problem -- but it does at least guarantee an optimal solution in polynomial time.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to just iterate forwards a day at a time, allocating any relevant and unallocated work items to that day in order of delivery date (so that those with the tightest deadline are allocated first and all available capacity is used).  On a day by day basis you can then see available spare capacity or if there is a capacity shortfall (which would be when after allocating all available capacity in this manner there are 1 or more work items with a delivery date equal to the current date).

e.g. in C# something like :

```
        public class WorkItem
        {
            public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
            public DateTime DeliveryDate {get;set;}
        }

        public class ProductionCapacity
        {
            public DateTime Date {get;set;}
            public int Capacity {get;set;}
        }

        public void AllocateWork(ProductionCapacity[] productionCapacity, WorkItem[] workItems)
        {
            // tackle work items in order of delivery date
            var activeWorkItemList = workItems.OrderBy(w => w.DeliveryDate).ThenBy(w => w.StartDate).ToList();

            // iterate a day at a time
            foreach (var day in productionCapacity.OrderBy(p => p.Date))
            {
                // get the set of work items we can handle on this day
                var workWeCanDo = (from w in activeWorkItemList where w.StartDate <= day.Date && w.DeliveryDate >= day.Date select w).Take(day.Capacity);

                // Remove them all from the active workitems list
                foreach (var workItem in workWeCanDo)
                    activeWorkItemList.Remove(workItem);

                Console.WriteLine("Handling " + workWeCanDo.Count() + " work items on " + day.Date + " - spare capacity of " + (day.Capacity - workWeCanDo.Count()));

                var workWeCannotDo = (from w in activeWorkItemList where w.DeliveryDate <= day.Date select w);

                if (workWeCannotDo.Count() > 0)
                   Console.WriteLine("** Over capacity by " + workWeCannotDo.Count() + " work items on " + day.Date + " **");
            }
        }
```

Spare capacity by date range gets a bit trickier as there are more variables, i.e. the ability to shift work forwards in time to create capacity.